# Node.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Tags: javascript, node.js

NOTE: I fixed this setting the [server.keepAliveTimeout](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_keepalivetimeout)

I'm trying to fetch a large amount of data from a `MongoDB` database and after ~25 seconds the request fails and return:

> net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

This is the code that returns the data to the client:

```
router.get('/:run_id', authenticate, (req, res) => {
  const runId = req.params.run_id;

  let tagHierarchy = [];
  mongoService.pullRunReports(runId)
  .then((result) => {
    for(const [_, runReport] of result.actLiteReports.entries()) {
      tagHierarchy.push(runReport.tagHierarchy);
    }
    tagHierarchy = Array.prototype.concat(...tagHierarchy);
    res.status(200).send(tagHierarchy);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  })
})
```

---

It seems that the HTTP connection times out after 5 seconds even if the content is not completely downloaded...Is there any way to increase that limit?

Every time I get different content size even if the data is always the same and the request fails after waiting around 5 secs for the content to be downloaded

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) it says the default timeout is 2min.

You can check if you issue is related with the server timeout by using `server.setTimeout` function and doing some console.log in the callback.

Comment: This may have to do with chrome... Did you check FF? I remember I had problems like this in a meteor app

Comment: FF does the same

Comment: As you are sending "big data" you can also try to stream the result via res.write(chunk). But this may make new problems with json handling.

Comment: I fixed setting the server.keepAliveTimeout